# sizeof() function in structure

Tags: c, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    char c;
    int d;

 }t;

 typedef struct
 {
      int a;
      char c;
      char d;
      char e;
      int f;

 }t1;

int main()
{
    printf("sizeof t = %d", sizeof(t));
    printf("sizeof t1 = %d", sizeof(t1));
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof t = 12
sizeof t = 12
```

Without using #pragma pack(), sizeof operator is returning same value for two different structure. Could you please explain?

Comment: Padding/alignment, probably. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: `int` has sizeof 4 and alignof 4 on your machine.

Comment: See also this question: [Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing)

Comment: I am surprised though that the 3 chars in the second struct are actually packed.

Comment: structs have to be aligned to the lowest common multiple of their members' alignment. Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes and a `char` is 1, `t` is 9 bytes aligned to the nearest multiple of 4 = 12 bytes and `t2` is 11 bytes aligned to the nearest multiple of 4 = 12 bytes.

Comment: @ElanHamburger no. `t` is 12 bytes aligned to 12. if `char` came last only then there would be padding bytes at the end.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala 4 + 1 + 4 = 9?

Comment: @ElanHamburger The members are not reordered. `int; char; int; char;` would have sizeof 16 on this computer. Though the sum of sizeofs of members is 10.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala but that's due to the alignment requirements of the struct. 9 bytes are in use, 3 bytes are padding due to the struct.

Comment: Just for completeness: `sizeof` is not a function, it's an operator.

Comment: @ElanHamburger a `struct` doesn't in itself have any alignment requirements. Only the members have. `t` is 9 bytes aligned to the nearest multiple of `12` is wrong. It is the `a` and `d` that have the alignment requirements.

Comment: In addition, don't print size_t with the %d format specifier, it invokes undefined behavior. Use %zu instead.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You're right that in this case the alignment is due to the members' alignment requirements (I phrased my initial comment incorrectly), but structs absolutely have their own alignment requirements (what if you wanted an array of structs?).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala ["Note that the alignment of any given struct or union type is required by the ISO C standard to be at least a perfect multiple of the lowest common multiple of the alignments of all of the members of the struct or union in question."](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html)

Comment: See stack Doc on [structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/4590/structure-padding-and-packing)